# Can a mother taste her own breastmilk?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, children-parenting, dairy, baby-infant

Can a mother drink/taste her own breastmilk?

I know theres an *issur* for a non-baby to drink directly from the breast; but, what about from a cup?

Further, if it is indeed *assur* (even from a cup), what about "tasting" it (i.e. to see if it's gone bad) as one might "taste" chicken soup to see if it needs salt (without actually eating it so you're not *fleishik* and it doesn't require a *bracha*)?

Comment: Sort of related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/31959

Comment: Very related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22376

Comment: Why is there an Issur for an adult to drink directly from the source?

Comment: @ElShteiger Usually, only if you can eat an animal's meat can you drink its milk (based on the principle of היוצא מן הטמא טמא). This is the exception. There's a rabbinic prohibition for adults to nurse directly from a human so as not to come to think you can nurse directly from other non-kosher mammals.

Answer (score 18):

Human breastmilk is 100% kosher once it has left the woman's body ([Shulchan Aruch YD 81:7](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x4190)). Furthermore, it is [pareve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareve), but shouldn't be cooked with meat to avoid issues of [Marat Ayin](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/615/759) ([ibid. 87:4](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x4215)).

Comment: And 100% disturbing. +1

Comment: @doubleaa , you should add that it can be collected in a vessel or even ones hand and then he could drink it