# Human cultured meat

Tags: kashrut-kosher

I've read meat cultured from a kosher source is kosher too, though nobody seems to know whether that's meat or parve. I've also been told one can consume flesh from a dead person in an extreme survival situation, and moreover that's parve.

So my question is what about meat cultured from a living person's flesh? There is no desecration of a dead body. And would it be parve too?

Would it make any difference whether the human source is anyone at random or, for instance, one self?

People swallow their own blood when gums bleed without even knowing it.

Comment: You can consume meat from a pig (or anything else) in an extreme survival situation as well. Note that swallowing blood from inside your mouth is permitted as long as it never leaves your mouth but swallowing blood from any other part of your body is forbidden by the rabbis.

Comment: And milk and meat only applies to kosher animals, so pork would be parev.

Comment: human is pareve http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/36104/759

Comment: ...why *wouldn't* it be pareve? I'm not sure I understand the question. Why would synthesizing something normally pareve make it meat?

Comment: "meat cultured from a **living person's** flesh" Wouldn't that be *eiver min hachai*?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11269/does-artificial-meat-grown-in-a-petri-dish-have-the-halachic-status-of-meat/30438#30438 Note that meat must be cultured from a kosher animal that has been slaughtered properly. Thus, cultured meat from a nonkosher source is not kosher.

Comment: @Ploni no aiver min hahai is only by animals and birds https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Yoreh_De'ah.62.1?with=all&lang=bi

Comment: @hazoriz That's excluding fish and grasshoppers 9see Ba'er Hetev there). It doesn't say that it doesn't apply to humans.

Comment: @Ploni and it does not say it does

Comment: @hazoriz http://boards.fool.com/as-humans-have-neither-a-true-hoof-nor-chew-their-20032896.aspx

Comment: @Ploni see the second prisha on the siman, that there is no aiver min hachay on, animals from a non kosher species https://www.sefaria.org/Tur,_Yoreh_Deah.62.1?with=Prisha&lang=bi,  so it whould seem the burden of proof is on you that there is aiver min hahai on something other then kosher animals and birds

Comment: @hazoriz see the link I just posted.

Comment: @Ploni nice, but see the beer haitiv on the ramo that he quotes, it says nothing about aiver min hachay https://www.sefaria.org/Ba'er_Hetev_on_Shulchan_Arukh,_Yoreh_De'ah.79.4?lang=bi or you can see the original shach 79.3 that there is no lav to eat meat sposificly from a living person http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x4185

Comment: @hazoriz You can answer the OP's question with that ramo.

Comment: @Ploni sorry I am not sure it is so simple (you answer it). on the tzuras hadaf (link in my comment above) on the right side גליון מהרש״א brings an option that it is aiver min hahai

Comment: @hazoriz regardless it would answer the question. The only discussion would be **why** it's *assur*.

Comment: @Ploni but it seems everyone agrees that things coming out of it I.e. milk and blood is not osser (exsept marris ayin), so maybe cultured meat is like blood and is permitted

Comment: @hazoriz milk and blood are by-products of a person. Flesh is the actual person.

Comment: Welcome to mi yodeya!

Answer (score -1):

If human meat can only be consumed in a life threatening situation what would it matter if it is parve? Your example of blood from gums is covered in the kitzur. It's not considered consuming blood as it is considered as having not left the body unless it is first spit out