# Why is breast milk considered parve?

Tags: food, meat-and-milk

Refer to [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/36102/5275) regarding whether an adult is allowed to drink human breast milk.

While there is controversy about the health benefits of drinking breast milk, some doctors recommend it for cancer patients or those with digestive or nutritional problems. (See [here](https://www.seattletimes.com/nation-world/some-ill-adults-use-breast-milk-to-fight-disease/).) Why would breast milk be considered pareve, while milk from kosher animals is considered dairy?

Comment: What's your default about what status milk has? It does come from basar, maybe it's a chiddush milk is dairy, and that chiddush doesn't apply by humans. Therefore the milk would have the same status as humans. Are humans parve?

Comment: @robev Are you trying to confuse me more? LOL. It's an interesting question. But, based on sabbahillel's answer, it seems that non-kosher animals get no status of either meat or dairy. I understand that. If you ate human flesh, you could drink cow's milk immediately afterwards. (Sadly, there was at least one era when Jews ate human flesh.)

Comment: Deer milk is also Pareve (at least biblically). Are you wondering why the rabbinic rules extending the laws of meat and milk to other land animals don't also apply to humans?

Comment: @DoubleAA why are deer considered different? For 2nd question - yes, that's exactly it. Although, I **think** sabbahillel has answered that question, but, I'm not sure.

Comment: @DanF Deer is like chicken. Only בהמה domesticated animals are real meat/milk.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, human meat(!) is also kosher parve, and so is human blood.

Comment: @SAH Anything non-kosher is considered "pareve". *Basar Vechalav* applies only to kosher items. If you ate a non-kosher hamburger, you could have dairy immediately afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

The halacha of a human being is considered separate from the halachos of animals. Thus, animal milk from a kosher animal is dairy, while milk that is not kosher would not have the extra restrictions of dairy (since it is not kosher anyway). However, human beings are not considered in the laws of animal food. It appears that the definition of *dairy* is milk from a kosher animal, which does not apply to a human being. The main halachos of this are mesorah from

> לא תבשל גדי בחלב אמו

[Breast Milk: Just Like Honey From a Bee?](https://www.thejewniverse.com/2012/breastmilk-just-like-honey-from-a-bee/)

> By way of explanation, one contemporary rabbi compares mother’s milk
>   to honey—as a similarly exceptional case of kosher food derived from a
>   non-kosher animal.

That is, bee honey is explicitly shown as kosher, since Yonasan ate it. Breast milk is explicitly shown as being given to Yitzchak, Moshe, and Shmuel which implicitly shows that is is kosher in that the Tanach references it as a normal food. This is the case even though the source is not a kosher animal. We also see that an infant should not nurse from a woman who has eaten non-kosher food if it can be avoided.

[Shulchan Aruch YD 81:7](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x4190)

Thus, [Is Breast Milk Pareve?](http://www.yeshiva.co/ask/?id=1208) points out that it is pareve, while not giving the specific reason. However, the cooking of meat in it is asur because of *mar'is ayin*.

> It is forbidden to cook meat in breast milk ([Shulchan Aruch YD 87:4](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x4215)). Your baby
>   need not wait between eating meat and nursing.

While [Rambam Ma'achalot Assurot - 3:2](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/968259/jewish/Maachalot-Assurot-Chapter-3.htm) says it is permitted, he does not go into the reason it is pareve.

> Human milk is permitted to be eaten,<sup>3</sup> although the meat of
>   a human is forbidden to be eaten. We have already
>   explained<sup>4</sup> that it is forbidden by virtue of a positive
>   commandment.<sup>5</sup>
>
> <sup>3.</sup> I.e., even by an adult. Note, however, Halachah 4.
>
> <sup>4.</sup> Chapter 2, Halachah 3.
>
> <sup>5.</sup> Thus it does not contradict the general principle
>   mentioned in the previous halachah.

[Mother’s Milk and Kosher Laws](http://www.jewishanswers.org/ask-the-rabbi-category/mitzvos/kosher-food/?p=3090)

> Additionally we don’t find (other than the story of Moses – which I’ll
>   mention soon) that there is a prohibition to drink milk from a
>   non-Jew. Milk is a separate entity in itself, which is permitted by
>   the Torah when coming from a human female, whether Jewish or
>   non-Jewish. It can be compared to honey which is not considered
>   non-kosher, even though it’s coming from a non-Kosher insect, the bee.
>
> However, on a more esoteric level, our Rabbis tell us that what a
>   person eats affects his soul. We know that the quality of a mother’s
>   milk is influenced by what she eats; therefore it follows that if she
>   ingested non-Kosher food, traces of that would come into the milk.
>   Therefore, although in terms of Jewish law there is nothing wrong with
>   giving the baby donor-milk from a breast milk bank, if it would be
>   convenient, and there would be a donor available who keeps Kosher who
>   would be happy to pump some milk for the baby (e.g. a sister or close
>   friend), this would be preferable.

Comment: _It appears that the definition of dairy is milk from a kosher animal, which does not apply to a human being._ It is not clear what your source for this is. The first link says nothing about it. Rambam says nothing about it. And your second link says nothing about it. In short nowhere here do I see an answer to the question.

Comment: @mevaqesh The fact of not waiting between meat and breat milk implies that it is parve (not just kosher). The fact that Rambam explicitly says it is permitted means that it is kosher.

Comment: The questioned wasn't about kashrut, but about the status. Additionaly, the question wasnt binary; it was looking for the reason. Rambam says nothign about any of this.

Comment: _Breast milk is explicitly shown as being given to Yitzchak, Moshe, and Shmuel which implicitly shows that is is kosher in that the Tanach references it as a normal food_ Huh? Yitshak and Moshe were babies before the Torah was given. How does that implicitly show anything about the laws of kashrut? Even Samuel was a baby. It is false to claim that something once fed to a baby is presented as normal food in Tanakh. Does Tanakh state that babied may only eat food that is kosher? Remember, the question wasnt even if it is kosher. Giving a lot of mostly irrelevant info hurts rather than helps.

Comment: @mevaqesh Yes, I said he does not. I included him for completeness and to show that it is kosher so that I could then go further and show it is pareve. The main reason was the connection to honey.

Comment: _The fact of not waiting between meat and breat milk implies that it is parve_ Huh? According to the view of all the Geonim, even adults need not wait an amount of time between meat and actual milk! Even many of those who disagree concede that this is just a minhag. The fact that babies don't practice a minhag is no proof whatsoever about the laws of kashrut! Given that this is the only line that even approaches an answer, why not delete all the other distractions and focus on developing this into an answer.

Comment: @mevaqesh The basic chain of logic is 1. breast milk is kosher *lechatchilah* even for an adult (per Rambam) 2. Breast milk is only asur to cook with meat because of *mar'is ayin* (per Shulchan Aruch) 3. Therefore the halachos of breast milk are not because of dairy and it is pareve.

Comment: 1. The OP already knows it is permitted. 2. The OP already knows it is pareve. The question is why, and besides for it s other flaws, this rambling post seems to indicate that you don't know the answer to the OP's question, as you dont clearly address it. || _It appears that the definition of dairy is milk from a kosher animal_ Is your only line addressing the question. Actually sourcing it (and noting the sources stated reasons) and just deleting everything else would tremendously improve this.

Comment: "The main halachos of this are mesorah from

לא תבשל גדי בחלב אמו" Huh? What does it even mean to be a mesorah from a verse? Is it an Oral tradition, or understood from a verse? Do you mean that an Oral tradition interprets the verse? How do you know that this detail is part of the Oral Tradition?

Comment: @mevaqesh The point is that the halacha of breast milk is like the halacha of honey a totally different gzeiras hakasuv from milk from a kosher animal. As a result, the halachos are different. Breast milk is seen to be pareve because cooking meat in it is *mar'is ayin*. That is what I said at the beginning. The rest was attempting to address your comments.

Answer (score 0):

In regard to the reason breast milk is considered pareve.

Min Ha'Torah it is clear that other than milk or meat from Goats and the like(Domestic Animals)no milk or meat is subject to these laws.

The Chachomim added certain milks and meats to be subject to these laws Mi'Drabbanan.

Consumption of human milk is something done only for explicit reasons such as a baby who has got nothing else or the sick who is in need of this milk.Now,we find in Hilchos Yom Kippur Siman 718' that there are differing opinions whether or not a person who has got to eat on that day should make Kiddush. The reasoning of those that do not require Kiddush is since the Chachamim weren't mesakein a kiddush for those remote cases.

We find all over in Shas that by a milsa d'lo shechiaca the Chachamim did not put their rule as in Gemarah Gittin where the Gemarah says that in a case such as two people bringing a Get since it is a remote case the Chachamim did not place the Halach of Befony Nichtav(even though if they would keep things the way they are it would naturally be subject to it).

So too here Chachamim weren't mesakein a Halacha of Bossor Be'Cholov when it  applies in seldom cases only.

Comment: Interesting idea. Is it your own? Incidentally the milk is completely permitted, not just for babies and sick people. It could be people don't usually drink it without reason, but that's just due to availability and culinary styles, not for any halakhic reason.

Comment: To make this answer better, you might want to have a look at https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1607/4940